# Div not rendering html tags

Tags: html, css

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to get the div to render the html elements properly. Any ideas? The text is taken from a database and inserted into the div via Handlebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping):

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", `{{{`.

Comment: You Sir, are correct.